# Angular - How to test Guards with ActivatedRouteSnapshot RouterStateSnapshot and GlobalState

Tags: angular, testing, redux, guard, karma-coverage

I'm creating unit test for my Angular app but i don'k know create tests for my custom guard that use Redux.

This is my code of the guard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, CanLoad, Route, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlSegment, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { first, map, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { GlobalState } from '../state/app.reducer';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { RolesAccount } from 'src/app/pages/auth/interfaces/auth.constant';
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdministratorGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {
 
  constructor(private route: Router,private store: Store<GlobalState>) {}
 
  canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.isAdmin()
  }
  canLoad( route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.isAdmin()
  }
 
  isAdmin():Observable<true | UrlTree>{    
    return this.store.select('authentication').pipe( 
      first(), // take of first value
      map(userStore => userStore.userLogged?.role || ''), 
      //TODO we hardcode the email of administrator until role is in JWT
      map(role => role === RolesAccount.ADMIN ? true : this.route.createUrlTree(['/home']))
    );    
  }
}
```

I run `npm run coverage`

And this is the uncovered block (I need create unit test for `canActivate, canLoad, and isAdmin`

[Uncovered block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZSyD.jpg)

And this is my unit testing file (default testing)

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { AuthComponent } from 'src/app/pages/auth/auth.component';
import { IUserState } from 'src/app/pages/auth/interfaces/auth.interfaces';

import { AdministratorGuard } from '../administrator.guard';

fdescribe('AdministratorGuard', () => {
  let guard: AdministratorGuard;
  let store: MockStore<IUserState>;  

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
          [
            {
              path: 'auth',
              component: AuthComponent
            },
          ]
        ),
      ],
      providers:[
        provideMockStore({}),
      ]
    });
    guard = TestBed.inject(AdministratorGuard);
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(guard).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Wesley for your comment.
Here's the solution

This is my code of guard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, CanLoad, Route, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlSegment, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { first, map, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { GlobalState } from '../state/app.reducer';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { RolesAccount } from 'src/app/pages/auth/interfaces/auth.constant';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdministratorGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {

  constructor(private route: Router,private store: Store<GlobalState>) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<true | UrlTree> {
    return this.isAdmin()
  }
  canLoad(): Observable<true | UrlTree>{
    return this.isAdmin()
  }

  isAdmin():Observable<true | UrlTree>{    
    return this.store.select('authentication').pipe( 
      first(), // take of first value
      map(userStore => userStore?.userLogged?.role || ''), 
      //TODO we hardcode the email of administrator until role is in JWT
      map(role => role === RolesAccount.ADMIN ? true : this.route.createUrlTree(['/home']))
    );    
  }
}
```

And this is the test

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { lastValueFrom, of } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthComponent } from 'src/app/pages/auth/auth.component';
import { RolesAccount } from 'src/app/pages/auth/interfaces/auth.constant';
import { IUserState } from 'src/app/pages/auth/interfaces/auth.interfaces';

import { AdministratorGuard } from '../administrator.guard';

describe('AdministratorGuard', () => {
  let guard: AdministratorGuard;
  let store: MockStore<IUserState>;  
  let defaultState:IUserState = {
    authentication:{
      userLogged:{
        name:'',
        email:'',
        phone:'',
        accessToken:'',
        refreshToken:'',
        role: RolesAccount.USER
      },  
    }  
  }
  beforeEach(() => {
    const routerStub = {
      events: of('/'),
      createUrlTree: (commands: any, navExtras = {}) => {}
    };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
          [
            {
              path: 'auth',
              component: AuthComponent
            },
          ]
        ),
      ],
      providers:[
        provideMockStore({
          initialState:defaultState
        }),
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub}        
      ]
    });
    guard = TestBed.inject(AdministratorGuard);
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);

  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(guard).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('can Activate to be True ', () => {
    const storeSpy = spyOn(store, 'select').and.callThrough();
    guard.canActivate()
    expect(storeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('can canLoad to be True ', () => {
    const storeSpy = spyOn(store, 'select').and.callThrough();
    guard.canLoad()
    expect(storeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })

  it('validate role ADMIN',async () => {
    const nextState:IUserState = {  
      authentication:{
        userLogged:{
          name:'Test',
          email:'mailTest@gmail.com',
          phone:'+5411557788',
          accessToken:'asfksakmfaskmfsakm',
          refreshToken:'safla25l4235lllfs',
          role: RolesAccount.ADMIN
        },    
      }     
    }

    store.setState(nextState);

    const isAdmin = await lastValueFrom(guard.isAdmin())

    expect(isAdmin).toBeTrue()
  })

  it('if is not admin,navigate home',async () => {
    const nextState:IUserState = {  
      authentication:null
    }

    store.setState(nextState);

    const isAdmin = await lastValueFrom(guard.isAdmin())

    expect(isAdmin).toBeUndefined()
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With how you have it defined you would need to add your guard to the auth path that you have defined.

```
RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
[
  {
    path: 'auth',
    canActivate: [AdministratorGuard],
    component: AuthComponent
  },
]),
```

Then in your `it` you would need to route to your 'auth' path to fire that guard.

Now, I don't like this approach for the following reason - you are testing that the RouterTestingModule behaves like the real RouterModule.

Instead I would suggest testing your guard like a service.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({

    providers: [
      AdministratorGuard,
      provideMockStore({}),
    ]
  });
  guard = TestBed.inject(AdministratorGuard);
  store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
});

it('should allow canActivate', (done) => {
  // ... setup to allow it to return true
  guard.canActivate(null, null).subscribe(x => {
    // code to make
    expect(x).toBe(true);
    done();
  });
});

it('should deny canActivate', (done) => {
  // ... setup to return false
  guard.canActivate(null, null).subscribe(x => {
    // code to make
    expect(x).toBe(false);
    done();
  });
});
```

Then add your other tests for canLoad to do the same. You may need more than one true/false scenario for each. You won't want to test the `isAdmin` function directly as it isn't the public interface for this service.